# Crew on a planet or moon with frozen world-wide ocean who are attacked by mechanical automatons

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this a few years ago (maybe five years) and can't quite recall everything about it. But the gist is, there is a crew on this planet or moon with a world-wide ocean under the frozen surface. They're attacked by these mechanical automatons, and one of the crew members is killed while getting out of the shower on the ship, I think. Cold air rushes in immediately and he freezes nearly instantly. They end up following these machines under the surface and eventually find that there is no core; it's just *all* liquid, and there's a sort of portal at the center of the planet (UPDATE: I mis-remembered that part.  There is a core, but there is a portal hatch in the ground under over 1000 km of liquid).

I seem to recall there may have been mind uploading as well. I think they made backups of themselves? Maybe? At the end, one member goes through the portal and it's just black space (again, mis-remembered... there is definitely more than black space).

I can't remember much else. Anyone remember anything like that?

Comment: Can you provide any limits on when "a while ago" was in terms of a year range?  Did you read it online or as part of a hardcopy anthology?

Comment: I have a policy of commenting on why I downvoted: The title is solidly unhelpful, and the all-caps are a bit much.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 - It was a few years ago, maybe 5?  And I seem to recall there may have been mind uploading as well.  I think they made backups of themselves?  Maybe?  At the end, one member goes through the portal and it's just black space.  I'm so sorry it's all so vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found it. It was a story called [**Return to Titan**](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1148297) by [Stephen Baxter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Baxter_(author)) from a 2010 science fiction compilation book called [Godlike Machines](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/9432650) edited by  Jonathan Strahan.  It's technically part of what's called Baxter's [Xeelee Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeelee_Sequence), which is an overall scifi universe setting for many of Baxter's stories and books.

I had to backtrack all of my ebooks over two computers and 6 years (I have about 300 GB of ebooks alone... not counting audiobooks).
Ironically, Baxter is one of my favorite authors.  It's so sad that it's not a more well-known story... because re-reading it now, it's really excellent.

It's far more complex than I remembered it.  I remembered only bits and pieces, and mis-remembered parts like the ending.  The planet is Saturn's moon Titan, and really, it starts as a sort of scheme of a multi-billionaire and his friends to kidnap a somewhat corrupt (but inherently good) government worker in order to get him to rubber stamp the OK on their plan to exploit Titan's resources.  The government worker is the protagonist, and he works determining if extraterrestrial life is sentient.  If it is, there are strong legal protections for them and their environment.  So if any sentient life is found on Titan, it'll be off-limits for good.  When they get to Titan, they realize there are these large mechanical "spiders" in addition to the huge swath of life forms in Titan's ocean (all of them non-sentient).  But if there is no sentient life, where did the robotic spiders come from, who built them?  Some bad things happen, they get stranded, have to explore more... and things move on from there. It's really quite good.

I encourage you all to check it out. Stephen Baxter's "Return to Titan".  Enjoy.

Comment: Hi, it's great that you found it!  You could improve your answer by including a few more details about the story, especially if you misremembered anything in the question.

Comment: I just edited my answer to explain more about the story.  How's that look?

Comment: Looks good - an improvement could be to add links to ISFDB and/or Wikipedia for the book and author

Comment: ^_^ And don't forget you can accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark tomorrow (self-answers require a 48 hour cool-off period).